# use image picker to save photos to 2 different image view (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I want the user to take 2 different photos using 2 different imageviews and buttons (a left and right side). I know how to do this with using imagepicker Delegate but not with 2 different imageviews. Both imageviews will have different photos and use a different button to take the photo. Basically the left and right sides have nothing to do with each other. 
[image: simulator pic]

code

```
    import UIKit

class _vc: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var leftImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var rightImage: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func takePhotoLeft(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func takePhotoRgith(_ sender: Any) {
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `tag` the simple option is to make one instance property of type `UIImageView` name `currentImageView` in your ViewController and then in your left and right Button action set that `currentImageView` with `leftImage` and `rightImage`. After that in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` set the selected image to this `currentImageView`.

```
var currentImageView: UIImageView?

@IBAction func takePhotoLeft(_ sender: Any) {
    self.currentImageView = self.leftImage
    //ImagePicker code
}

@IBAction func takePhotoRgith(_ sender: Any) {
    self.currentImageView = self.rightImage
    //ImagePicker code
}
```

Now in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method simply set image to this `currentImageView`.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.currentImageView?.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is the code to put into the buttons  if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            
            
            
            
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
?

Comment: You need to set image to this currentImageView as I have mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do it would be to set a variable on your viewController to keep track of which button was pressed most recently.  You could even use something as simple as an `Int`, like `var imagePickerButton: Int = 0`, and assign the numbers to the buttons however you like.  I like to use the `tag` attribute so I don't have to think about it.  If you do that, in your button action, you can say `self.imagePickerButton = sender.tag` before doing your imagePicker launch code.

Then, in your `didFinishPicking...` method you can use `switch` or if/else to decide which imageView to populate, like

```
switch self.imagePickerButton {
case 0:
    leftImageView.image = image
case 1:
    rightImageView.image = image
etc.
}
```

There are tons of ways you could handle this, but this is a very easy, quick one.